# Docker Express.js not serving static files due to redirect to HTTPS (also a problem with Fastify)

Tags: node.js, docker, express

And also reproducible is this repo https://github.com/patarapolw/docker0000

I am opening `http://localhost:8080` in Chrome Version 80.0.3987.163 (Official Build) (64-bit) / macOS 10.15.3 MacAir 15 inch

It gets redirected to `https://localhost:8080` every time.

```
├── package.json
├── public
│   └── index.html
├── server.js
├── .dockerignore
└── Dockerfile
```

```js
// server.js

const app = require('express')()
app.use(require('express').static(
  require('path').join(__dirname, 'public')
))
app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('Go to http://localhost:8080')
})
```

```
# Dockerfile

FROM node:12-alpine
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm i
COPY . .
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

```js
// package.json

  "scripts": {
    "start": "docker run -p 8080:8080 express-sample",
    "build": "docker build -t express-sample ."
  },
```

Error message is

- This site can’t provide a secure connection
- localhost sent an invalid response.
- ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Must be some Chrome security...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome has cached a redirect to `https`, you need to clear it:

- Go to: `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` > `Delete domain security policies`
- Enter your domain and click delete.
- You may need to clear browser cache too: chrome://settings/clearBrowserData (`Cached images and files`)

As an alternative you can use another domain for developing that isn't cached, you can do that by editing `/etc/hosts` file and adding:

```
127.0.0.1 dev.foo
```

And then access to `http://dev.foo:8080`

Comment: Should I enter `localhost:8080`. No response on delete, and still cannot open localhost.

Comment: just enter: `localhost` which is the domain.

Comment: No change. Still redirects.

Comment: Is that happening in other browsers? Want to make sure you don't have anything on the code.

Comment: It seems to be OK in Safari.

Comment: delete it in `#hsts`, close chrome (all tabs, al windows), and then open it again. As an alternative you can check my updated answer.

Comment: Also, you may need to clear browser cache. chrome://settings/clearBrowserData